# Office script: link workbook & make vlookup formula

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I am trying to make an office script to do below functions:

1. User clicks button to navigate and select excel workbook in Sharepoint.
2. Vlookup formula is generated based on selected workbook.
   *vlookup lookup range is set, only workbook is dynamic.

I have made this work with VBA, but after moving to Office 365.
I wanted to make it into office script, as more users are using browser or team version of the excel.

Thank you, in an advance.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) are you willing to explore using power automate to run the office script on a dynamic file? 2) is it a requirement that the user sees the result in Excel almost instantly (as if the file is opened) or can it be done unattended and opened later?

Comment: 1) Yes, I also have been looking through power automate, and power automate+office script. But I am yet unfamiliar with the power automate. 2) It will be best for the user to see it instantly after dynamic selecting the file.

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible with Office Scripts and Power Automate to create realtime cross-app interactions such that the user presses a button in workbook A and the user would instantly see a new file which is dynamically chosen (workbook b) and opened with the script already run or running. I believe your best approximation would be to define some trigger in power automate (could be recurrence) that runs the script on workbook b and returns a link to that workbook in email or simply saves it to sharepoint/onedrive.

Comment: Yeap, after looking various sources and tutorials. I think I will stick to VBA until Office Script and Power Automate gets more features. Thank you so much!